# how to replace 'LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK' (U+200E) - <200e> with vim

Tags: linux, vim

Thats is how this special character is displayed in vim:

[image: LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK]

Ive tryed with `/\x20(\x0e|\x0f)/` and `/\xe2\x80[\x8e\x8f]/` without results.

Comment: This post helped me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59447/replace-unicode-chars-in-vim

Answer (score 8):

First, if you want to replace byte 0x20 (it is space, if I am not mistaking), you need to use `\%x20`, not `\x20` because `\x` designates a hex digit (unless used inside a collection, there `\x20` means what expected). But if you want to replace given unicode character, you should use `\%u200E` (`\u200E` inside a collection).

Second, both `\%x20` and `[\x20]` will match character with unicode code 0x20, not byte with code 0x20. It does not matter for the space, but makes difference for code points >0x7F.

Answer (score 4):

Try to replace `\u200e` :)

You can test this works by inserting that character into your buffer, and seeing that it appears as `<200e>`, if you type this in while in insert mode: `<C-R>="\u200e"<CR>` (that's CTRL+R and `<CR>` means ENTER)

Answer (score 3):

I would put the cursor on the blue `<200e>`, then type `yl` to yank (copy) the character.

Then, type `:%s/<C-R>"/replacement/g`

(where `<C-R>` is `Control+R`, of course).

Comment: Also, since we already know the desired code point, the character can be inserted without yanking by using `<C-v>u200e`. See [`:help i_CTRL-V_digit`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-V_digit).

Answer (score 2):

Use your terminal's mechanism for entering characters by Unicode codepoint. In the case of gnome-terminal, that's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> followed by the hex code (e.g. `200e`) and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: interesting, I didn't know this